# Two conditions in ISERROR formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

I have a formula to highlight cells red in a column (column D) which represents progress in %:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH("P",$G5:$X5,0))
```

i.e. if within the range `$G5:$X5` there is no 'p' then highlight the cell red.

I now need an additional condition where the % can only be =>90% AND not contain 'p' for it to be highlighted red. I have tried:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(MATCH("P",$G5:$X5,0))), $D5=>90, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what the condition is you want but please try:

```
=AND(MAX($G5:$X5)>=0.9,ISERROR(MATCH("P",$G5:$X5,0)))
```

in place of the formula shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477678/1505120).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's brilliant